# Qaction how to call in Pyqt6

Tags: pyqt6

I'm trying to call a Qaction using design in my .ui file. I can't find a way to call it. In button we can call it using code like below

`self.window.mybutton.clicked.connect(self.startmyfunction)`

how about in Qaction. Please see screenshot below on my design about Qaction
[ui image of Qaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MP9N.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, we can just easily use `triggered.connect`

For example:

```
self.window.mymenuhost1.triggered.connect(self.myfunctionexample)
```